# Source for Lie groups and Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

In classical mechanics, an observable is a bounded continuous function $f$ on a phase space, which can be assumed to be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for some $n$. If $f$ is differentiable, then:
$$\frac{df}{dt}= \{f,H\}$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the theory and $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ denotes the usual Poisson brackets.

It is said that the above expression implies that $H$ generates the action of time translations. I have no background in Lie groups and Lie algebras, and I would like to understand sentences such as the latter. In short, I would be able to understand what is a Lie group and a Lie algebra, what is an action of time translation, how it is connected with infinitesimal generators, symmetries in physics and so on. For this reason, I am looking for good mathematical references.

I am really interested in its applications to physics, specially classical mechanics, but I am looking for mathematical (i.e. rigorous) resources. In addition, I know these concepts arise naturally in differential topology, but I am not very familiar with manifolds and so on, so I would like a discussion which avoids these concepts. Any suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: I would read Arnold’s classical mechanics. This line of thought ends up leading to the connection between classical mechanics and symplectic geometry I believe. You’re not going to be able to understand Lie groups without understanding some differential topology

Comment: For Lie groups and Lie algebras there are many classical resources. Depending on your prerequisites you can either first begin with Lie algebras (mainly assuming vector spaces and linear algebra), or Lie groups (mainly assuming manifolds and basic differential geometry). Usually any book with the title "mathematics for physicists" has this, too.